# SeekTo does not trigger onPlaybackStateChanged in MediaControllerCompat

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I have this media player and everything else works properly, I start the song, it gets through 2 states, the last one being `PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING`

Therefore we can say the callback is registered. The problem is whenever I trigger the SeekBar listener, the method `seekTo` does not trigger the `onPlaybackStateChanged` and because this does not happen, I cannot update the SeekBar to its new progress. This only concerns the UI. The music actually is playing from the progress after modifying the SeekBar progress. What's more, the trackDurationTextView doesn't get updated either. It changes its value while I'm dragging my thumb across the seek bar but once I release it, it goes to its initial progress, same as the seek bar.

Here is where there callback is registered.

```
@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        if (service instanceof MediaPlayerService.ServiceBinder) {
            try {
                mediaController = new MediaControllerCompat(this, ((MediaPlayerService.ServiceBinder) service).getService().getMediaSessionToken());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaController.registerCallback(mMediaControllerCallback);
        }
    }
```

This is how the callback is initialized:

```
 private MediaControllerCompat.Callback mMediaControllerCallback = new MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(@NonNull PlaybackStateCompat state) {
            updatePlaybackState(state);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMetadataChanged(MediaMetadataCompat metadata) {
            if (metadata != null) {
                updateMediaDescription(metadata.getDescription());
                updateDuration(metadata);
            }
        }
    };
```

This is the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`

```
trackSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                trackDurationTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(progress / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                stopSeekbarUpdate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                //TODO: look here! the seek bar position is not kept when the user slides it!
                mediaController.getTransportControls().seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                scheduleSeekBarUpdate();
            }
        });


 private void updateProgress() {
        if (mLastPlaybackState == null) {
            return;
        }
        long currentPosition = mLastPlaybackState.getPosition();
        if (mLastPlaybackState.getState() != PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED) {
            // Calculate the elapsed time between the last position update and now and unless
            // paused, we can assume (delta * speed) + current position is approximately the
            // latest position. This ensure that we do not repeatedly call the getPlaybackState()
            // on MediaControllerCompat.
            long timeDelta = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -
                    mLastPlaybackState.getLastPositionUpdateTime();

            currentPosition += (int) timeDelta * mLastPlaybackState.getPlaybackSpeed();
        }
        trackSeekBar.setProgress((int) currentPosition);
    }
```

This is the place where mLastPlayBackState.getPosition should return the new value after the seek bar is updated, but it always returns 0 since the onPlaybackStateChanged never gets called. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this? I am facing a similar issue where seekTo starts the playback but the state is not updated.

Comment: What is the code in your `Callback.onSeekTo`? Where do you call `mediaSession.setState()`?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `MediaControllerCompat.Callback.onPlaybackStateChanged(PlaybackStateCompat state)` is only called if the `MediaSessionCompat`'s `PlaybackStateCompat`'s `state` changes. If the `PlaybackStateCompat`'s `position` changes while the `state` remains unchanged, `onPlaybackStateChanged(...)` never gets called. So I assume by "onPlaybackStateChanged", the API is more specifically referring to the `PlaybackStateCompat`'s `state` and not the `PlaybackStateCompat` itself.

To get around this, I temporarily update the `PlaybackStateCompat`'s `state` to `PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_REWINDING` or `PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_FAST_FORWARDING` after a seek command to trigger `onPlaybackStateChanged(...)` on the UI so that I can update the `SeekBar`'s position and elapsed time `TextView`'s text to the new playback position.

**UPDATE**: I can no longer reproduce this issue. I'm not sure what exactly I changed to fix it either. My first suggestion for you is to verify that you are calling `setState(state)` on your `mediaSession` object where `state` is the `PlaybackStateCompat` that contains your updated `position` value. This wasn't the solution for me, but it's where I would look first.

Comment: I am still facing trouble with this. Is there a foolproof answer?

Comment: can you help me? My MediaControllerCompat.getMediaController(getActivity()).getPlaybackState().getState() always returning STATE_NONE

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem and found a working solution. Basically, as Ryan suggested, you need to call the MediaSession's or MediaSessionCompat's setPlaybackState(). My project is based on [Google's older Android Music Player Codelab Github repo](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-music-player) so I'm using a playback manager which keeps track of a MediaPlayer and also has a callback for when the state changes. So when the manager's seekTo() gets called, it sends the state through the callback to the MusicService (a subclass of MediaBrowserServiceCompat), which keeps track of the MediaSessionCompat. session.setPlaybackState(state) is really the key line in MusicService.kt below.

PlaybackManager.kt:

```
class PlaybackManager(private val context: Context, private val callback: Callback)
    : AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

   /* A bunch of stuff not important to this answer goes here */

   /* mediaPlayer gets set to a MediaPlayer at some point */

    fun seekTo(position: Long) {
        mediaPlayer?.seekTo(position, MediaPlayer.SEEK_CLOSEST_SYNC)
        updatePlaybackState()
    }

    private fun updatePlaybackState() {
        callback.onPlaybackStatusChanged(PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(getAvailableActions())
                .setState(state, getCurrentStreamPosition().toLong(),
                        1.0f, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
                .build())
    }

    interface Callback {
        fun onPlaybackStatusChanged(state: PlaybackStateCompat)
    }
}
```

MusicService.kt:

```
class MusicService : MediaBrowserServiceCompat() {

    private lateinit var session: MediaSessionCompat
    private lateinit var playback: PlaybackManager

    val callback = object: MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {

       /* Other methods like onPlay() and onPause() go here */

        override fun onSeekTo(pos: Long) {
            playback.seekTo(pos)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        session = MediaSessionCompat(this, "MusicService")
        session.setCallback(callback)
        sessionToken = session.sessionToken

        playback = PlaybackManager(this, object: PlaybackManager.Callback {
            override fun onPlaybackStatusChanged(state: PlaybackStateCompat) {
                session.setPlaybackState(state)
            }
        })
    }

    /* Other methods like onDestroy(), onGetRoot() and onLoadChildren() go here */
}
```

More useful code to look at is [the Google Universal Android Music Player Sample Github repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer)